# HTML invalid validation

Tags: html

HTML:

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th style= "width: 10%"> Quantity </th>
        <th style= "width: 47%"> Info </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I tried validating with XHTML 1.0 Strict, but it's telling me that there is no attribute style for the width element in this HTML version. Is there another way I can write the width without having validation problems?

Comment: The `border` and `width` attributes have been deprecated in favour of CSS a long time ago.

Comment: You must mean the validator says that there is no attribute `width` for the `table` element. (In future, copy and paste the error message.)

Comment: Or you must mean something completely different. The fragment is actually valid XHTML 1.0 Strict.

Comment: @Kolink, those attributes, for those elements, have not been deprecated in any published HTML specification, including XHTML 1.0. In HTML5 (which is work in progress), the `width` attribute for `table` is declared obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

The `width` attribute on `table` does *not* cause a validation problem with XHTML 1.0. But if you wish to get rid of it for other reasons, you can replace it by CSS code that sets the `width` property to the value `100%`. A simple way to do this is to replace the attribute by a `style` attribute with suitable value:

```
<table border="1" style="width: 100%">
```

It is generally better to use an external style sheet, or at least a `style` element, rather than `style` attributes, however.

Other answers have addressed the question of replacing the `border="1"` attribute, too, although this was not asked for. It would be slightly more complicated, since that attribute affects borders between cells, too; see my [Mapping presentational HTML to CSS](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html2css.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest assigning an `id` to the [table](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.1) and then styling it in an external [CSS](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/) stylesheet. But this should be sufficient to validate:

```
<table style="border: 1px solid black; width: 100%;">
    <tr style="border: 1px solid black;">
        <th style="width: 10%; border: 1px solid black;"> Quantity </th>
        <th style="width: 47%; border: 1px solid black;"> Info </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Invalid CSS. When fixed (to have `1px` instead of `1`), creates a border around the entire table only, not between the cells, as `border=1` does.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I guess that's right, but then to imitate the deprecated `border = 1`, he'll have to use an external stylesheet. I've updated my answer.

Comment: An external style sheet is generally the best approach to styling, but it is not *needed* for the purpose. One can use `style` attributes on `td` elements or, more reasonably, a `style` element.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela That's true. In this case using inline styling, though ugly and not semantic, should be sufficient to imitate `border = 1` _and_ validate both HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to define `width` and `border`:

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th class="q"> Quantity </th>
    <th class="i"> Info </th>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table{
    width:100%;
    border: 1px solid magenta;
}
.q{
    width: 10%;
}
.i{
    width: 47%;
}
```

Comment: or can I do
<th class ="one"> Quantity </th>
<th class="two"> Info </th> ?

Comment: The answer is wrong if it is supposed to produce the same effect as the HTML attribute `border="1"`. This can be seen by comparing the rendering of the original markup and the HTML and CSS in the answer.

Comment: The “fixed” CSS code is invalid, as you can see e.g. by using the W3C CSS Validator. Even when actually fixed, it does not replicate the effect of `border="1"`.